# Deleting a Elasticsearch Snapshot

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-snapshot

We have a elasticsearch cluster running on EKS, and we have configured a daily snapshot for the cluster onto S3. We have now a lot of data piled up on S3, and for cost optimisation we are planning of deleting any snapshots older than 2 weeks.

However since the snapshots are incremental, we are not sure whether deleting the older snapshots will corrupt the new ones or not.

**So my query is can we safely delete the older snapshots from S3 using the DELETE Api from Elasticsearch without corrupting any new snapshots??**

Comment: This answer might help you understand how snapshots work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64499292/4604579

Comment: Thanks @Val. i was looking for the same. The explanation is perfect

Comment: The last paragraph in my other answer linked above actually answers your question

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** you can safely delete older snapshots from S3 using the DELETE Api from Elasticsearch without corrupting any new snapshots.

Elasticsearch make sure that it only delete those data from repository which are **no longer referenced by any other existing snapshots** .

Ref :https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/delete-snapshots.html